# AWS Athena not recognizing date?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have two environments - prod and test.
I am trying to figure out a query for Athena to show me access logs only for a specific month.

I am doing that based on a column 'date' with YYYY-MM-DD format, the underlying data are gzipped .txt files in s3.

My logs are limited to past 2 months.
Because i want to automate the query, i rather use the interval month subtraction.

So - when running on test environment the clause below returns correct responses, showing me lines that have month of august
`WHERE month(date) = MONTH(current_date - interval '1' month)`

unfortunately when running on prod, i get july and august.

It feels like i tried everything and still cant figure out what's wrong.
I tried subselects, casting both sides of WHERE statement to VARCHAR , literally nothing seems to make an impact.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: And what is the date which leads to such behaviour?

Comment: i have logs starting from 2022-07-01 up to 2022-09-01.
>WHERE month(date) < subtracts month from >date< column. 
month(current_date - interval '1' month) is supposed to return >8<. And it does in both test and prod environment. But somehow the Where clause doesn't care

Comment: Have you checked what is `current_date` on the prod environment?

Comment: yes, it results correctly with todays date, 2022-09-01

Comment: Try including as columns in your SELECT the values month(date) and MONTH(current_date - interval '1' month) to help you debug it. Also, having a column called “date” is probably not a good idea as that is normally a reserved word so may be causing confusion. It would probably also help if you updated your question with the complete SELECT statement and some sample data

Comment: try WHERE month(date) = '08' or WHERE month(date) = '8' to see what values it pulling up. If it is pulling both months then is date a partition column? If not what can you add select distinct '$path' to your query where you get two months data for one month? It will help you to identify the source of these rows.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who stumbles upon my issue again :)
i found an answer - a dirty one, but working nonetheless.

My original query that Athena didn't care about month i wanted

```
SELECT date,
    time,
    bytes,
    request_ip,
    method,
    uri,
    status,
    user_agent
FROM "default"."logs"
WHERE month(date) = MONTH(current_date - interval '1' month)
AND user_agent LIKE '%gecko%';
```

a working query showing the month i wanted:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT date,
    MONTH(date) as mn,
    time,
    bytes,
    request_ip,
    method,
    uri,
    status,
    user_agent
FROM "default"."logs"
WHERE user_agent LIKE '%gecko%') as in_table
WHERE mn = MONTH(current_date - interval '1' month);
```